# Invoke method with interface from string

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to run a strategy pattern using config values. Since I don't know the strategy until runtime I need to get it via reflection then invoke it, but this is failing. Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
// a DTO where deserialised data ends up
public class PoDtoA { /* ... */ }

// a different DTO where deserialised data for a different strategy ends up
public class PoDtoB { /* ... */ }

public interface IConversionStrategy<TDto>
{
    TDto? Deserialise(string data);
}

public class ConversionContext
{
    public TDto? Deserialise<TDto>(
        IConversionStrategy<TDto> conversionStrategy,
        string data
    ) => conversionStrategy.Deserialise(data);
}

public class JsonStrategy<TDto> : IConversionStrategy<TDto>
{
    public TDto? Deserialise(string data) => data.DeserialiseJson<TDto>();
}

public class XmlStrategy<TDto> : IConversionStrategy<TDto>
{
    public TDto? Deserialise(string data) => data.FromXml<TDto>();
}
```

If the strategy is known at compile-time then I do this (for example) and it works correctly:

```
string po = "{ ... }";
PoDtoA strategy = new JsonStrategy<PoDtoA>();
PoDtoA poDto = new ConversionContext().Deserialise(strategy, po);
```

When the strategy is not known at compile-time then I cannot simply replace the `strategy` part because `ConversionContext().Deserialise()` is inferring the type (`PoDtoA` or `PoDtoB`) from the first arg, and if that arg has no type at compile time then it won't compile - as far as I know anyway. This gives the following error:

```
// get the type for JsonStrategy<PoDto>
string strategyName = "JsonStrategy";
string dtoName = "PoDtoA";
Type strategyType = Type.GetType($"my.project.{strategyName}`1[[my.project.{dtoName}]]");
var strategy = Activator.CreateInstance(strategyType);
var poDto = new ConversionContext().Deserialise(strategy, po);
```

> Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'ConversionContext.Deserialise(IConversionStrategy, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

So I'm trying to invoke `ConversionContext.Deserialise()` using reflection but that's where I'm stuck (`strategyType`, `strategy` and `po` are defined above):

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(ConversionContext).GetMethod(nameof(ConversionContext.Deserialise));
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { strategyType });
generic.Invoke(new ConversionContext(), new object[] { strategy, po });
```

Its compiling fine but I'm getting a runtime error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Object of type 'my.project.JsonStrategy`1[my.project.PoDtoA]' cannot be converted to type 'my.project.IConversionStrategy`1[my.project.JsonStrategy`1[my.project.PoDtoA]]'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the method with the type `TDto`, now you're using `JsonStrategy<TDto>`

```
var dtoType = strategyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { dtoType });
```